# Refrencing A NSMutableArray In A Different Class For containsObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray

I'm in call `DetailsViewController` trying to use the following code if,

```
([[FavViewController myFavsTwo] containsObject:_word])
```

but getting error: **No know class method for selector myFavsTwo**

in `FavViewController`, I have it set like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myFavsTwo;
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You can only access `property  myFavsTwo` using object of `FavViewController`. And how `DetailsViewController` is shown?

Comment: At some point...but my DetailsViewController is connected to a few other controllers -- I just want to add something to FavViewController and check that it's not already there yet

Comment: replace if ([[FavViewController myFavsTwo] containsObject:_word]) with if ([FavViewController.myFavsTwo containsObject:_word]).

Comment: @Girish now getting this error: Property 'myFavsTwo' Not Found On Object Of Type 'FavViewController'

Comment: First create the object of FavViewController & then access the array.

Comment: @user3306356 does `DetailsViewController` is navigated from `FavViewController`?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr it can be

Comment: Read the error message: No know class method for selector myFavsTwo (by the way, copy+paste avoids giving us incorrect error messages). You know what a class method is? Does FavViewController have a class method named myFavsTwo? Is it supposed to have one? Or does it have an instance method named myFavsTwo? You realize that your code tries to call a class method, because it doesn't have an instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[FavViewController myFavsTwo]` will call **class method** in FavViewController like this:

```
+ (NSMutableArray *)myFavsTwo{
   ...
}
```

`@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *myFavsTwo;` will only create **instance accessor methods**, and you can get `myFavsTwo` like this:

```
FavViewController *favVcInstance = [[FavViewController alloc] init];
if ([[favVcInstance myFavsTwo] containsObject:_word])
```

So, could you understand why crash happen so far?

Answer (score 3):

i guess you are using the variable `myFavsTwo` with Class name. You should use instance of `FavViewController`. Make sure you have created getter and setter methods or used `synthesize`.

Comment: +1, properties are always accessible through object(instance) of a class.

Comment: You don't need to create getter or setter methods, or use @synthesize, since those are both done automatically if you create a property.

Comment: Not totally following...sorry kind of new to all this...myFavsTwo is being synthesized so I don't really know what the error is about

Comment: @user3306356 Do you know how to create an instance of a class?

Comment: No I don't know how to do that -- Or -- if I do know how to do that then I don't know it's called creating an instance

Comment: @user3306356 `FavViewController *object = [[FavViewController alloc] init]`. This creates an instance for you. Btw, if you are new to ObjectiveC I'd recommend learning it before you start coding. It will save you a lot of time.